# How to pass an array to an update statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, groovy, jira

I would like to execute an update on a variable number of rows. I tried the following but it does not work.

```
def sernos = issue.getCustomFieldValue (ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(10719))
def update = '''update mytable set status = 'reserved' where id in (${sernos})'''
sql.executeUpdate (update)
```

I get an error from Postgresql:

> syntax error at $

It seems to me that Groovy does not expand the GString. `sernos` is an ArrayList of Strings. The following code:

```
log.warn (sernos.getClass())
log.warn (sernos[0].getClass())
```

Reports:

```
2020-10-15 12:09:06,926 WARN [runner.ScriptBindingsManager]: class java.util.ArrayList
2020-10-15 12:09:06,926 WARN [runner.ScriptBindingsManager]: class java.lang.String
```

I also tried this:

```
def update = '''update mytable set status = 'reserved' where id in (${Sql.expand(sernos)})'''
```

But it does not work either.

How to pass a list of Strings to a SQL `where` condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're sending would produce a query with invalid SQL syntax, something like

```
update mytable set status = 'reserved' where id in ([a, b, c, d])
```

Where `[a, b, c, d]` is the `toString()` result of the list. You need to convert that to a text that's suitable for an `IN` clause:

```
def inText = sernos.collect{"'$it'"}.join(', ')

//also, you need double quotes (" or """) for GString interpolation
def update = "update mytable set status = 'reserved' where id in ($inText)"
...
```

That will set `update` to a value similar to

```
update mytable set status = 'reserved' where id in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Now, you need to be careful with the content of `sernos`, because the above would still produce invalid SQL syntax if the text in the list contains single quotes. You'd have to escape them if that's expected.

Comment: But this builds the SQL by string concatenation and opens the door to SQL injections.

Comment: @ceving you seem to be using dynamic parameters anyway. If `sernos` is coming from your users, then of course you should be wary of doing anything like this to start off.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
def sernos = issue.getCustomFieldValue (ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(10719))
def questionmarks = sernos.collect {'?'}.join (',')
def update = """update mytable set status = 'reserved' where id in (${questionmarks})"""
sql.executeUpdate (update.toString(), sernos)
```